# Terminate the Grace Period When the Post Score Changes

Tags: feature-request, voting, grace-period

This is a follow-up to [Terminate the grace period when a post receives a flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274059/terminate-the-grace-period-when-a-post-receives-a-flag).

Terminating the grace period for flags was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) because it would be confusing for users as flags do not have any visible mark. However, it was suggested in the answer that terminating because of voting would make more sense. This is a feature request to implement exactly that: **Terminate the grace period when a post's score changes, or when it receives a vote**.

The benefits of implementing this would be

1. As mentioned in the earlier post, flags, especially serious "red" flags, would not be invalidated by the sneaky edit of the poster.
2. Currently, to terminate the grace period, we have to comment. It's time-consuming, and for those of us that don't have a userscript installed to add from a set group of comments, it's too cumbersome that we either have to joke in the comments or abandon doing it altogether.
3. The longstanding [Can't change vote if the answer was edited too quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78442/vote-cant-be-changed-if-answer-is-edited-too-quickly) would fix itself.

The only downside to this I can think of is the potential increase in the number of revisions for a post. But for me at least, if I see that I don't have to rush against a five-minute window to correct typos in my newly typed question, I would make my edit more substantial. This is also assuming that the post does receive a vote and the grace period *is* terminated, which is usually not the case.

When a question is voted on the first minute of it being posted, either it's terribad and will be deleted eventually, taking all the revisions with it, or is stellar and those are few anyway. In other words, its two extremes of the spectrum, not the normal questions.

Therefore, among the similar solutions to this, like terminating with flags, recording every revision anyway etc. this seems like the best solution.

How does it sound?

Comment: Can we get rid of the grace period altogether? Now that revisions don't cause auto-CV, and bump abuse is being handled manually, there's not much need to keep their count low.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I confess I greatly appreciate the ability to make snap fixes of dumb mistakes I should have caught earlier, even though I suspect I'm at the upper end of the spectrum of caution before posting. So removing the grace period would be rather unfortunate.

Comment: @Jan I do think the grace period is a useful feature. They help organize revisions into what would otherwise be a long mess, so I don't want them to go. The grace period edit of rude/abusive posts is the only thing imperfect about it, and I want that to change.