# End the edit grace period upon two or more spam/rude flags being raised

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam, offensive, grace-period

I am aware that a [similar suggestion was made and rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274059/terminate-the-editing-grace-period-when-a-post-receives-a-flag). The major criticism of that one was essentially this

> The only problem with this is it's unexpected - there's no visible trace on that post to indicate to the user why their grace period didn't apply. Seems like it'd be more sane to drop the grace period on something like a vote, which is publicly visible, and is automatically triggered by a spam/offensive flag anyways.

The flipside is that you get things like [this formerly rude answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49131959/revisions). It's not obvious to anyone why it was rude-flagged out, but [Metasmoke remembers](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/109160) (it's filled with an inappropriate word over and over). The poster edited the post just seconds before the final flag came in. This is a poor experience for flaggers and moderators alike, as the history of why the action was taken is gone.

I'm hoping we can maybe tweak the original proposal to cover both concerns.

1. Raise the bar to two flags instead of one
2. Limit this to just spam/rude

It covers the concern that a user might not understand why their grace period expired (your spam/rude answer is collecting multiple downvotes), and ensures that a single user can't end it by themselves. If more than one person thinks it needs immediate removal, that should lock in the post as it exists at that moment.

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139950/347191 . According to this, if one were to comment on or before flagging it will end grace period.So there is a possible workaround.

Comment: I don't think a single user locking it in is a problem. That's already the case with comments.

Comment: Reading animuson's answer there, I think the potential solution is the same... voting locks it. It's also worth noting that even mods can't see these edits (as far as I'm aware), which is really troublesome.

Comment: @Catija I think the issue wasn't so much the number of users, as it was making it obvious that flags were being raised. I tend to agree that raising a single flag of any type shouldn't remove the grace period because it's transparent to the user why that happened. Even a -1 wouldn't be enough to let the user know something is amiss. A -2 in under 5 mins, however, should be a red flag to any user, and it's a lot easier to argue that a user can connect those dots more readily.

Comment: Not really. Spam and R/A flags come with an automatic downvote... which means that the person who flagged can also downvote. There's no way for the user to tell the difference between two rude flags and one rude flag plus a manual downvote.

Comment: @Catija Is there really any person that can see posts edited during the grace period? I think such edits overwrite the revision history in the DB directly so no one knows it, and that's the problem.